# use of .size() and don't work in my project?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Did you can help me that why don't work following code in my project?
My project: [see this link](http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/accommodation/show) -> please go to select box or input box and select or typed value.

```
var length_pa = $('#pagination a').size();
    if(length_pa >= 16){
        $('#prev_pag, #next_pag').show();
        $('#pagination').css('float','left')
    }else{
        $('#prev_pag, #next_pag').hide();
    }
    if(length_pa == 0){
        alert('0000000000')
        $('#hesar_number').hide();//.css('display','none');
    }
```

**EDITE:** Sorry, my mistake in typing the code here.
Now What is cause problem?

Comment: -1 Don't just paste code here with a problem; look at the browser error console, the manual, the code itself. Don't expect everyone to do everything for you.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake in typing the code here.
Now What is cause problem?

Comment: As both answers have stated, you were missing a `.` in the code. My point, however, still stands.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#hesar_number')hide();
```

should be:

```
 $('#hesar_number').hide();
```

And you don't have an element with ID clock which is throwing another error in `show`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake in typing the code here.
Now What is cause problem?

Comment: you are missing a period: $('#hesar_number').hide();

Comment: did must change `id` to `class`?

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo in your JS, which is killing the script:

```
    $('#hesar_number')hide();//.css('display','none');
                      ^--- missing a .
```

Absolutely ANYTIME you are working with Javascript and run into trouble, check your browser's JS console (shift-ctrl-J usually). This error would've jumped right out at you if you had.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake in typing the code here.
Now What is cause problem?

Comment: Well, the dropdown is now changing the number of rows being displayed for me in FF6... so what's the problem now?

Comment: my problem is dot't work top code. `if(length_pa >= 16)...else...if(length_pa >= 0)`. what do i do? [i test in FF6 but don't work]

Comment: what "don't work"? Some more details would be nice, as I don't think too many people here read that language (Farsi?)

Comment: yes, i'm farsi. did you know farsi? don't work "show" and "hide" for `#prev_pag, #next_pag` with change length(number) in "var length_pa" `$('#pagination a')`. did worked for you? (see: http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/accommodation/show)